# Meteor コレクションの static プロパティ, メソッドの定義方法について

Tags: meteor

Meteor のコレクションプロパティ・メソッドの定義方法についての質問です。

```js
// articles.js
Articles = new Mongo.Collections('articles');
```

例えば、上記のように Articles コレクションを定義しているとして、この Articles コレクションに独自のプロパティやメソッドを定義したいのですが、どうすればよろしいでしょうか。

独自で定義したプロパティやメソッドには以下のようにアクセスしたいと考えています。

```js
// プロパティへのアクセス
Articles.someProperty

// メソッド呼び出し
Articles.someMethod()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

そのままできます。

```
Articles.someProperty = 'abc';
Articles.someMethod = function() { return 'abc'; };
```

Collection2などでも独自プロパティを使っています。
これがどの程度一般的に受け入られているのかはよく分かりません。